# Session Values Null In My Callback Function But Readable After Redirect

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I have a action like this

```
        public IActionResult Callback(IFormCollection form)
        {

            if (!HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue(SessionName, out byte[] info))
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));

            ....
        }
```

When my provider redirect this function i can't read any session values.
But if i add another step with redirection like this;

```
        public IActionResult Callback(IFormCollection form)
        {

            return RedirectToAction("CallbackCheck");

        }

        public IActionResult CallbackCheck()
        {

            if (!HttpContext.Session.TryGetValue(SessionName, out byte[] info))
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));


        }
```

I can read all session values.

Add `Startup.cs` to these configurations but nothing changes

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

           ...

           services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options => options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None);
           services.AddSession( );

           ...
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add parameters to Session solve problem

```
            services.AddSession(options =>
            {
                options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;
                options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
                options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
            });
```